# Sapphiere HD 5770 - 3 monitors

Tags: video, graphics-card, dvi, displayport

I have a Sapphire HD 5770 and I'm trying to connect 3 monitors.

I have:

- 2x DVI
- 1x Displayport

I installed the latest CCC driver but my menu is not the right one. It can only activate two monitors at the same time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to just light the monitors or create a display group?  If you just want extended desktop, try using Windows display properties.

Comment: Ok, i think the problem is my old win xp. Right?

Comment: @Shinrai - I dont have the option to create a group :(

Comment: Oh, these screenshots were NOT taken by you?  You should clarify that - I saw the first one and assumed you had the option and were also running Vista/7.  You are correct.

Comment: My reputation is to low so i cant post 2 images :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you are limited to two outputs on this card when running Windows XP.  Sounds like it's time for an upgrade!

Comment: Right! It works very well with Windows 7 :)